Find out keyboard identifier for X11
I have a custom keyboard layout for my default laptop keyboard and other keyboards added, which is set in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf like this:
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "dxkb"
        Option "XkbVariant" "main"
EndSection

But more recently I made a Lily58 keyboard and I'd like to make a variant of my keymap that automatically applies to the Lily58, but not other keyboards, like this:
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Lily58"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "dxkb"
        Option "XkbVariant" "lily58"
EndSection

the trouble is about how to find out the identifier of the Lily58. All the resources I've found just mention the identifier system-keyboard, but not identifiers for specific keyboards, and using Lily58 as above didn't seem to recognize the keyboard. How do I find out the right identifier for the keyboard?

The identifier is meaningless. You can set it to Identifier "Custom layout for my Lily58" and it will do the same thing (i.e. nothing).
Model specific restrictions are specified using the various Match* keywords, as can be found in the xorg.conf(5) manual page (and the note at the very end of the libinput(4) manual page). Xorg itself comes with a few such configurations in its 10-quirks.conf.
Xorg on Linux gets its device information from udev; I don't know if there is an easy way to get all "Match" fields for a given X input device, but the USB ID is an easy one – run lsusb and get the VVVV:PPPP number for your device and put it in MatchUSBID.


It seems that Xorg will dump the properties into xorg.log whenever it detects a device, but I don't know how to activate such logging.
The harder way to get Match fields is:

Use sudo libinput list-devices to find the /dev/input/event* path for the keyboard.

Run udevadm info /dev/input/eventXX and look at the 1st line to get its sysfs path. (It starts with /devices – edit it to /sys/devices. Udevadm is just like that.)

Trim the /event* from the end of the sysfs path, to get at the parent input* device, and run udevadm info on that. For example, my Logitech USB receiver is /sys/devices/pci…/…/input/input16.

Look for these properties:



udev
Xorg




NAME=
MatchProduct


ID_VENDOR=
MatchVendor


PRODUCT=
MatchUSBID but in a different syntax





Xorg will in fact also look for udev properties named XkbRules, XkbLayout, etc. and will directly import them into input device settings, so it's also possible to write an udev rule instead:
SUBSYSTEM=="input", NAME=="foo", ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="foo", ENV{XkbVariant}="foo"

